# Syntax: how to listen or an $emit in a Service?

Tags: angularjs

I want to listen for 'myEmittedEvent' on rootScope, but have a problem with this code:

```
app.service('MyService',function($rootScope){     
      $rootScope.$on('myEmittedEvent', function(){    <===== error here
           // code goes here
      });
});
```

The Browser console shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`  and the Brackets IDE says `Expected ':' and instead saw '.' - W116`

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

The `$rootScope.$on` code is fine in a controller. Even in my service - but only before the `return` part. I expect that it should be in the object which the service instantiates.

I am an Angular beginner, how do I `$on` or `$watch` in a service?

Comment: Looks valid...the only `.` is in `app.service` - is `app` declared? Is there something before this code?

Comment: Oops, my bad. I labeled the wrong line. It's the dot in  `$rootScope.$on`

Comment: all I see is an extra `}`, looks valid otherwise

Comment: +1 D'oh! Caused by my snipping the code when pasting it here. Ok, now it is valid (bracket-matching-wise at least), but still gets that error.

Comment: try do delete the semicolon after the last `}`. I mean `app.service('MyService', function(){});`

Comment: +1 but still a problem.

Comment: can you reproduce this in plunker?

Comment: Are you sure you copied/pasted the snippet correctly ? (I mean, we are supposed to find a syntax-error and have already done 2 copy/paste mistakes.) It sounds like you might have misspelled `function` somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try

```
app.service('MyService',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){     
  $rootScope.$on('myEmittedEvent', function(){    <===== error here
       // code goes here
  });

  return {};

}]);
```